# App Engine Launcher on Windows 7 X64

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been using Windows 7 on 32 bit and thought I would try X64. Setting up Google App Engine launcher when I run any application I get..

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 27, in 
    import fancy_urllib
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib__init__.py", line 341, in 
    class FancyHTTPSHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'
2012-03-13 09:33:00 (Process exited with code 1)

Cannot find nothing to say it is or is not supported on X64.  Any ideas?

Comment: works perfectly on mine so try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: I never managed it - For the moment I am on 32-Bit

Answer (score 0):

The App Engine SDK is now deprecated and will shut down at some point. More information on what you should migrate [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sdk-gcloud-migration)